Where should a Dart library file be?
Inside /lib/ I have a smaller library with some data models:
/lib
  /models
    model1.dart
    model2.dart

I would like to access them through a namespace, like var model = models.Model1();
I understand that for this I need to create a library, so I added models.dart (however due to alhabetic file sorting its right in the middle of the model files, already making things messy):
/lib
  /models
    model1.dart
    models.dart
    model2.dart

// models.dart
library;
part 'model1.dart';
part 'model2.dart';

I also added part of 'models.dart' at the top of moth model files.
I would like to not be able to mistakenly import the model files. Is there any way to... set them to private or something of the sort?
Also, where should models.dart be placed? Should it just be left in the middle of the rest of the library files?

You should export these files to use them as a library, not use part. Assuming you keep models.dart in the models folder, you can do the following:
/lib
  /models
    model1.dart
    models.dart
    model2.dart

// models.dart
library;
export 'model1.dart';
export 'model2.dart';

You can certainly move models.dart outside of the models folder without a problem also and I would personally prefer to do that depending on what else is in this package, just change the path for the exports:
/lib
  models.dart
  /models
    model1.dart
    model2.dart

// models.dart
library;
export 'models/model1.dart';
export 'models/model2.dart';


If you want to access it through a namespace, use the as keyboard when importing:
import 'package:{packageName}/models.dart' as models;


So you are saying part is deprecated and should never be used?

@RaresDima It's not deprecated (yet) as it does differ from exporting, but it's not of use for making this a library the way you want. There's another question with a couple answers that explain it nicely.
